# Create a new row that is the result of a calculation of rows above - Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df that looks like this:

```
period   value
  1        2
  2        3
  3        4
  4        6
  5        8
  6        10
  7        11
```

I need a way to calculate the values for period 8, 9, 10 by calculating the mean of the 3 previous periods. Eg. P8 = mean(8,10,11) = 9.6, p9 = mean(10,11,9.6) = 10.2, p10 = mean(11,9.6,10.2) = 10.3

Resulting in the following DF:

```
period   value
  1        2
  2        3
  3        4
  4        6
  5        8
  6        10
  7        11
  8       9.6
  9      10.2
  10     10.3
```

Comment: Will this be always the last 3 values? Perhaps run a for loop and then append to the frame?

Comment: I have thought of that. But is there a more efficient way of doing it.

Comment: If it is only 3 values, I think for loop is more than fine. Is it always 3 values?

Comment: Yes. I can get the mean of the last 3 values. But how do I create a new row (period and value) and append it to the df.

Comment: This is what i have: row_value = np.mean(df.tail(3)). then df.append(row_value) but that's missing the value for period

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate the required new sequence of periods, and keep on assigning the values i.e. period and `mean` of the prvious 3 values for each period using `DataFrame.loc`,

```py
newPeriods = (8,9,10)
for p in newPeriods:
    rowCount = df.shape[0]
    df.loc[rowCount] = [p, df.loc[rowCount-3:rowCount, 'value'].mean()]
```

**OUTPUT:**

```py
   period      value
0     1.0   2.000000
1     2.0   3.000000
2     3.0   4.000000
3     4.0   6.000000
4     5.0   8.000000
5     6.0  10.000000
6     7.0  11.000000
7     8.0   9.666667
8     9.0  10.222222
9    10.0  10.296296
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `period` as index first then run a for loop to calculate needed values and then set to the frame with `loc`. After the loop, we restore the `period` to be a column again. To keep track of last 3 values, we can use [`deque`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque):

```
from collections import deque

# keep `period` aside
df = df.set_index("period")

# this will always store the last 3 values
last_three = deque(df.value.tail(3), maxlen=3)

# for 3 times, do..
for _ in range(3):
   # get the mean
   mean = np.mean(last_three)

   # the new index to put is current last index + 1
   df.loc[df.index[-1] + 1, "value"] = mean
   
   # update the deque
   last_three.append(mean)

# restore `period` to columns
df = df.reset_index()
```

to get

```
>>> df

   period      value
0       1   2.000000
1       2   3.000000
2       3   4.000000
3       4   6.000000
4       5   8.000000
5       6  10.000000
6       7  11.000000
7       8   9.666667
8       9  10.222222
9      10  10.296296
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have k as your original dataset

```
period=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
value=[2,3,4,6,8,10,11]
k=pd.DataFrame([period,value]).T
k.columns=['period','value']

k=pd.concat([k,pd.DataFrame([[i,None] for i in range(8,11)],columns=['period','value'])])
for i in range(8,11):
    k.iloc[i-1,1]=np.mean(np.array([k.iloc[i-2,1],k.iloc[i-3,1],k.iloc[i-4,1]]))
```